# Single-word for a 'middle-ish' amount? Something between 'modicum' and 'plethora'

Tags: single-word-requests

I've tried the search here and a regular google-search, but it's possible my various queries have been either too broad or restrictive.

I'm looking for a one-word equivalent to "a fair amount".

A small (or even tiny, miniscule, barely notable) amount = "Modicum"
A large (or lavish, excessive, or wasteful) amount = "Plethora"

It seems like there should be a word in between those. All I've been able to come up with are "enough", which doesn't really feel right, and variations of the same phrase - "A reasonable/suitable/fair/adequate/decent/middling amount".

For context:
"He put a fair amount of thought into it"

OK, so 'plethora' wouldn't word there either, but something above 'modicum'. I may wind up just having to restructure the sentence, and that will probably be easier, but it's annoying me. Getting all up in my borderline OCD or something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking, as you accept an answer that doesn't fulfil your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **modest** amount

> 4 a :limited in size, amount, or scope

"Modest." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Sept. 2017.

Comment: 'Modest amount' is two words. OP doesn't seem to be too clear here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought he wanted a word to go in front of *amount*. I see your point, though.

Comment: Love it. I don't know why that one eluded me. "Modest" feels a bit closer to the low-end than "middle-ish, but it got me where I wanted to go. I really wanted to avoid using anything like "amount", "degree", measure", etc.

Cheking thesaurus results for "modest", I think I'll settle on a slight restructuring with "moderate". "Judicious" could be good too with a slight restructuring, but it feels a bit on the higher-end for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***sufficiency***. "He put a *sufficiency* of thought into it."

Answer (score 0):

> **Middling** (adj): moderate or average in size, amount, or rank. (from
>   ODO)

Some of its synonyms might work as well: average, middle-of-the-road, moderate.

Note that this can't be used as a single-word noun in the same sense, you would have to say "middling amount". Also, it has a negative connotation--it implies something is unremarkable or unimpressive. If you want something with a neutral connotation, you can use "**average**".

Comment: Not a noun. Contrast "Modicum" and "Plethora".

Answer (score 0):

How about any of the capitalized words in the example sentence:

Your honor, I am telling you the truth about the amount of alcohol I had in my system when they arrested me.  Again, it was the tiniest amount,  the officer was truly exaggerating when he said my level was HALF the legal limit, 50 PERCENT, DOWN THE MIDDLE, BORDERLINE, EQUAL, JUST RIGHT, MEDIUM, MOLLIFY,  EVEN, 
MEDICORE....just because I left a bar doesn't mean my alcohol level was MID HIGH.